# pwdump gives me blank passwords as hash although there are passwords?

Tags: kali-linux

I was trying to boot my brother laptop with USB stick containing Kali live in order to improve my knowledge as a cyber security specialist candidate. After I booted the system with Kali live and used pwdump to dump Windows's SAM file contents, I just found blank password hashes.

root@kali~:$ pwdump system sam

```
XXX:XXX:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::
XXX:XXX:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::
XXX:XXX:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::
XXX:XXX:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::
XXX:XXX:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::
XXX:XXX:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::
XXX:XXX:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0:::
```

But the computer uses passwords to login the Windows system. I mean pwdump should have dumped at least three real password hashes. But it didn't. Although system has passwords, why did pwdump give me just blank password hashes? Is it a new security prevention of Windows systems in the area of offline hacking?

Note: I'm using Kali Live 2016. The system which I deal with is Windows 10.

Note2: samdump gave the same result with pwdump and also lsadump, cachedump didn't work due to some python syntax errors.

Comment: I assume that you've updated all of your Kali packages?

Comment: I've updated packages, and also upgraded. But, not change. lsadump outputs "line 135, in get_file_secrets", "line 126, in get_secrets" and "line 66, in decrypt_secret". cachedump outputs "ERR:Couldn't find subkey PolSecretEncryptionKey of Policy".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the latest Windows Anniversary Update, Windows 10 seems to be using AES encryption on the SAM file, as well as storing information differently.

See this [tweet](https://twitter.com/gentilkiwi/status/762465220132384770).

Currently, pwdump doesn't appear to support extracting hashes offline in this new update, there's an issue posted on the GitHub page [here](https://github.com/Neohapsis/creddump7/issues/2).

You may have to sit tight and wait for an update, or look for an alternative tool.